# $P \to \lnot P: \lnot P$ in 11 lines

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

The tools that can be used are DNE, DNI, augmentation, MT, MP, &I, &E, and CP - nothing else. According to the Tomassi Logic Textbook, this should take 11 lines. I get the following 10 line solution.

{1}    1. $P \to \lnot P$                 [P]

{2}    2. $P$                              [A for CP]

{3}    3. $P \to \lnot P$                 [A for CP]

{2,3} 4. $\lnot P$                         [MP 2,3]

{2}   5. ($P \to \lnot P) \to \lnot P$   [CP 3,4, discharge 3]

{2}   6. $\lnot \lnot P$                      [DNI 2]

{2}   7. $\lnot (P \to \lnot P$)             [MT 5,6]

{ }    8. $P \to \lnot (P \to \lnot P$)     [CP 2,7 discharge 2]

{1}   9. $\lnot \lnot (P \to \lnot P$)           [DNI 1]

{1}   10. $\lnot P$                         [MT 8,9]

I'm probably being really dumb here, but I'm not seeing how to do this in 11 lines. What am I missing?

Comment: This proof looks correct, you don't have to write it in 11 lines.

Comment: @Manx, there are no solutions in the Tomassi book, only how many lines it 'should' take. He says this particular problem was 'exceptionally hard to solve [for a new student] with the limited set of allowed tools'. So, when I did it in fewer lines, not only did I doubt the proof waay more than I should have, I felt like I'd missed the obvious path. The only other way I see to solve this with these tools is to ditch the premise, derive the contrapositive of line 8, then use the Deduction Theorem to get ~P. The DT is mentioned in passing :/ Anyway, thanks for taking the time to look this over

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{l}\{1\}&1.&P \to \lnot P&[\mathsf P]
\\
\{2\}    &2. &P&[\textsf{A for CP}]
\\
\{3\}    &3. &P \to \lnot P&                 [\textsf{A for CP}]
\\
\{2,3\} &4. &\lnot P&                         [\textsf{MP 2,3}]
\\
\{2\}   &5. &(P \to \lnot P) \to \lnot P&   [\textsf{CP 3,4, discharge 3}]
\\
\{2\}   &6. &\lnot \lnot P&                      [\textsf{DNI 2}]
\\
\{2\}   &7. &\lnot (P \to \lnot P)&             [\textsf{MT 5,6}]
\\
\{ \}    &8. &P \to \lnot (P \to \lnot P)&     [\textsf{CP 2,7 discharge 2}]
\\
\{1\}   &9. &\lnot \lnot (P \to \lnot P)&           [\textsf{DNI 1}]
\\
\{1\}   &10. &\lnot P&                         [\textsf{MT 8,9}]
\end{array}$$

In a Fitch format that would be:

$$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\fitch{~~1.~P\to\lnot P}{\fitch{~~2.~P}{\fitch{~~3.~P\to\lnot P}{~~4.~\lnot P}\\~~5.~(P\to\lnot P)\to\lnot P\\~~6.~\lnot\lnot P\\~~7.~\lnot(P\to\lnot P)}\\~~8.~P\to\lnot(P\to\lnot P)\\~~9.~\lnot\lnot(P\to\lnot P)\\10.~\lnot P}$$

So, yes, those ten lines are valid, and you have used only the allowed rules — in fact only CP, MP, MT, and DNI.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, and thanks for giving me a markup example. I tried to use a table to do it, but I couldn't get it to work. As an aside, since Tomassi hasn't published any solutions, do you know if it would be legal for me to do so? Would I need to get permission? It's such a great book, but not being able to check things is annoying. I wouldn't be looking to charge for it, if that makes a difference?